# reference img in Angular2 form with typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, materialize

I am posting from my template to my angular2 an image with its name.

I select the image from my machine:

```
<input type="file" multiple (change)="fileChange(input)" #input />
```

the fileChange method is receiving the file and save it in the img tag below, so when I am ready to submit the form it is there:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <img [attr.src]='src' alt="" id="myphoto" name="myphoto" [formControl]="myphoto" />
    <input type="text" id="photoname" name="photoname" [formControl]="photoname" />
    <label for="photoname">Name</label>
</form>
```

in my photo.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from "@angular/core";
.....
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  // selector and templateurl
})

export class SendMyPhoto {
    myForm: FormGroup;
    ....
    constructor(builder: FormBuilder) {
      this.photoname = new FormControl("", []);
      this.myphoto= new FormControl("", []);

      this.myForm= builder.group({
        photoname: this.photoname,
        myphoto: this.myphoto
      });
    }
```

When I select the image from my machine, I get this error and the image doesn't display:

> core.umd.js:2838 EXCEPTION: Error in
>   /js/app/templates/myphoto.html:22:88 caused by: No value accessor for
>   form control with name: 'myphoto'

if I remove the

```
[formControl]="myphoto"
```

the image displays fine with no error, but then there is no way for me to reference it in the formbuilder in the typescript so I can send it to my server.

I already tried using formcontrolname instead of [formControl] but no difference in behavior

Comment: Are you using a img tag to upload an image? How? Is it a component? Don' you need to use an <input type="file" />? And for image upload you have to set `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form.

Comment: @vinagreti I update the question to answer your question

Comment: May be: `ìmg` tag is not an valid input, so there is no implementation for `formControl` in it. That is the reason you get the error. The second thing is that (I think) you are assigning the `src` value to a variable before transform the `input` in an `img` tag and that is the reason the image displays when you remove the `formControl`. So, I think you should get the `src` from the variable and not from `formControl`. What do you think?

Comment: yeah actually that's what I am doing right now with a getElementById. If that is the only way, then so be it. Please make your comment and I'll set it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be: ìmg tag is not an valid input, so there is no implementation for formControl in it. That is the reason you get the error. The second thing is that (I think) you are assigning the src value to a variable before transform the input in an img tag and that is the reason the image displays when you remove the formControl. So, I think you should get the src from the variable and not from formControl. What do you think?

You can implement an image input component and use the ngmodel to get the image data.

http://almerosteyn.com/2016/04/linkup-custom-control-to-ngcontrol-ngmodel